# How to change the properties with factory method in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have one class i am trying to overwrite it with factory design pattern but not able to do that..
 how to call it exactly to change the properties of object

```
function othername() {
var newobj = new Object();
    newobj.fname = "sachin",
         newobj.lname = "rawal",
             newobj.fullname = function () {
             alert(this.fname);
             }
             return newobj
}

var othername1 = othername ("hi","hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using prototype you can do it.

```
function othername() {
var newobj = new Object();
    newobj.fname = "sachin",
         newobj.lname = "rawal",
             newobj.fullname = function () {
             alert(this.fname);
             }
             return newobj
}

var othername1 = othername ("hi","hello");
```

prototype:

```
othername.prototype.middleName = "middleNameString";

var named = othername();
var md = named.middleName // md == "middleNameString"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Othername(fname,lname) {
    this.fname = fname || "sachin";
    this.lname = lname || "rawal";
};
Othername.prototype.fullname = function (){
    alert(this.fname + " " + this.lname);
};

var othernameDefault = new Othername (); //sachin rawal
var othername1 = new Othername ("hi","hello"); //hi hello
```